# Basic select component: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to make a `Select` component that takes in an array as a prop and turns it into `<option>`s.

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Select extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <select>
        {this.props.items.map((item) => (
          <option>{item}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  }
}

export default Select;
```

Render:

```
import React from "react";
import Select from './components/Select';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
          <Select items={['Volvo', 'Subaru']} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm getting `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

Comment: Add `console.log(this.props)` after render but before the return statement and see what you get

Comment: I tried your code but it seems working although there is warning about the `key`. https://jsfiddle.net/pj9dq8tf/ So I guess you don't pass the prop from another component.

Comment: Your example works fine here:   https://codesandbox.io/s/simpleselect-k6swz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` component doesn't know that its props has an `items` list in it, so you'll need to explicitly define it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface SelectProps {
  items: any;
}

class Select extends Component<SelectProps> {    
  render() {
    return (
      <select>
        {this.props.items.map((item) => (
          <option>{item}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  }
}

export default Select;
```

Answer (score 1):

For undefined error, You can use javascripts new ES2020 feature `?.` Also known as Optional Chaining

```
  <select>
      {this.props.items?.map((item) => (
              <option>{item}</option>
      ))}
  </select>
```

So this way if the items is undefined then you won't get an error

Comment: That's an awesome feature! Thanks for sharing